# One way upload to dropbox

Tags: macos, dropbox

I have large media files of several gigs that I want to upload to Dropbox without storing them on my computer. When I try and use the web portal for the upload, it takes several hours and my computer (Mac OS X) goes to sleep prior to the completion of the upload and I have start over.

Using the local Dropbox folder won't help me because I don't want the files on my computer.

Is there a way to prevent my computer from going to sleep during the upload or is there a native app solution to my problem?

Comment: Depending on how you want to answer the question, this may be more appropriate for Apple SE and not superuser.

Comment: @sunk818 How so? This question is perfectly on topic here and I don't see how migrating it to another site would change the way it can be answered. Please read this carefully: http://meta.superuser.com/a/2968/48078

Comment: The answer is to use Hot Corners which is a Mac OS X feature. The question, if you have to ask one, is how to prevent Mac OS X computer from sleeping during an upload. That's a very Apple specific question. If we're not going to separate Apple hardware/software questions from computer hardware/software questions, why even have an Apple SE?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this and I'm reciting this mostly from memory but it should work. Keep a backup of your files if this doesn't work.

1. Place the files to be uploaded inside a folder on the Dropbox folder
2. Dropbox will now upload the files.
3. When Dropbox finishes, go to the options menu and enable Selective Sync, disabling the folder you uploaded from syncing.
4. Exit the Dropbox app, then delete the folder.

Hopefully the files will still be online, without the Dropbox app having to sync them.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have 2 questions there. Doktoro Reichard has kindly furnished you with the answer to one, this ought to fix the other…

Set hot corners. Push the cursor to that corner & it won't nod off.

That would save you having to change the regular policy, for the times you do want it to sleep after being idle.

[image]